# Android 10 vs Android 7 BLE connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am facing a problem with my Android app connecting a RN4020 module. When I am building the app on a Samsung S7, I have success in connecting and transmitting data, but as soon as I am trying to do it with my note I am not able to connect. The device itself does not see any phone connected when using Note 9. On the module, it is a connection led which shows if a device is connected. When using the S7 the Bluetooth shows connection ( led on) but with the Note 9, the ledd is off.

```
// Open a BluetoothGatt connection to a BLE device given its address
public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {                             //Check that we have a Bluetooth adappter and device address
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");     //Log a warning that something went wrong
        return false;                                                               //Failed to connect
    }

    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false. 
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}
```

enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGsb0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVhmf.png)

```
// Open a BluetoothGatt connection to a BLE device given its address
public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {                             //Check that we have a Bluetooth adappter and device address
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");     //Log a warning that something went wrong
        return false;                                                               //Failed to connect
    }

    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
    } else {
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you show us the connection part code, so that we can suggest some chnages

Comment: Can you use for example the nRF Connect app and try to connect to the device? If it doesn't work, it's not an issue with your Android code.

Comment: I have tried several apps. But I am not sure they are updated so the bluetooth can work.

Comment: I think this topic is related to the problem. https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/samsung-android-10-ble-connectivity-regression/509/18

Answer (score 1):

Alex, there is an unresolved issue between the RN4020 and most (but not all) Samsung devices running Android 10. https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1129552.aspx describes the symptoms you have, so you may not get a coding resolution without a Samsung update. The Microchip forum does however describe a workaround to the RN4020 setup.

Answer (score 0):

For Android M and above in the `connect` method you have to pass transport type LE as argument.

I have written a general purpose Ble library in one of my apps, and so far it is working well. Make sure you are calling this method on the main thread.

```
 private boolean connectGatt(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }
        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
                .getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
        } else {
            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        return mBluetoothGatt.connect();
    }
```

Hope this helps!! Happy coding.

Comment: Are you passing transport type le in connect method

Comment: I have updated my post with the code I am using. I have tried both with and without the transport type and it is the same.

Comment: From what I know till the last week it worked without problems.